# preg_match random behavior

Tags: php, preg-match

I have, among others, these strings: "boards/", "localhost", "mysql", "0", "1", "Testing Board", "PLAIN".

I receive them as post data from a form. Some of these can have multibyte chars, but none of the test strings used has multibyte chars.

I run them through `if (!preg_match('/^./u', $str))`.

That if check mostly evaluates to false, ie the preg_match returns 1. But sometimes it evaluates to true, ie 0 from that preg_match.

The true (0) seems to come totally random. But if one of the strings evaluates to true then they all do. It's either all or none.

Do anybody have some sort of explanation to that seemingly random behavior? And maybe a solution to fix it?

Cheers 
Jari

Comment: can you give some examples of when the string doesnt match.

Also, 1 is true and 0 is false.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php preg_match returns int 1 or 0. Or false on error. That was not the question.

No, I cannot give any example. The strings where identical on all tests and the 0 seems to come randomly. I can't reproduce this at will. If I could do that I could also fix the error.

Comment: @tumba25 since 0 evaluates to `false` you'd better use `if (preg_match($pattern, $str) === 0)` to avoid confusion if `preg_match` will return false.

Comment: `That if check mostly evaluates to false, ie the preg_match returns 1. But sometimes it evaluates to true, ie 0 from that preg_match.` - you mean the other way around, presumably?

Comment: I was asking for more information from you because you havent provided much information for anyone to help you. examples of when it passes and when it fails would get you a quick answer

Comment: No. if (!1) 1 would be true but the if would evaluate to false. And the other way around for zero.

Comment: Please explain the regular expression. It just checks if there is one character in the string. Why not just use `strlen()` instead?

Comment: Want me to repeat that part about it seeming to be totally random and that I can't reproduce it at will? I provided all info that I have.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, it's just a little confusing the way you have written it

Comment: look at Jelmer's answer, I think that will solve your problem

Comment: @DaveRandom Could you rephrase in that case?

Comment: I'm to tired to read all my comments again. But I can't give any example on when it passes or when it fails. The code, form and post data is identical. I have checked that several times.

Comment: @tumba25 As far as I understood you submit the same string and the same pattern sometimes matches it and sometimes not, right?

Comment: @PLB the key thing that I missed is that it's being negated with `!` but it's phrased as if preg_match is returning the negated value

Comment: `if one of the strings evaluates to true then they all do` post the code you are running, not just the `if` line.

Comment: @PLB 
"As far as I understood you submit the same string and the same pattern sometimes matches it and sometimes not, right?"
Exactly.

Comment: That's pretty weird. Have you checked that input with preg_match in loop?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the warning in the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

> **Warning**
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

When you are running the `preg_match` on values as `0` and `1` it will return that match. Which will cause an evaluation to `true` when not handled correctly.

```
1 == true   //true
1 === true  //false
0 == false  //true
0 === false //false
1 == false  //false
1 === false //false
0 == true   //false
0 === true  //false
```

Comment: `if (preg_match('/^./u', $str) === 0)` Gives the same result. It is int zero it returns. I did try that but it still randomly evaluates that if to true. But mostly false.

Comment: @tumba25 What does it return when you `var_dump(preg_match('/^./u', $str));`?

Comment: To clarify. The code and post data where identical on all tests. Just pressed submit then the back-button and submitted the same form again. Everything in the code and in the form are identical for all tests.

Comment: Mostly int 1 but sometimes int 0. There are no code changes between the tests. If there where that could explain the behavior.

Comment: @tumba25 Can you add the string you want to match hardcoded in the `$str` variable? Instead of retrieving it from the `$_POST` global? And, `var_dump` your `$_POST`. I had it several times it was changing unexpected because of a programming mistake.

Comment: Yes, I'll test that. But a programming mistake would always give the same result on identical data.